# How to set properties of a custom types in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

Here is my Type Student:

```
type Student    = (String, Integer) -- name, id
alex = ("Alex", 42)
```

Is it possible to change id of Alex? I mean something like **alex.id = 10**

Comment: Too basic question question. Shows no effort. See http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#tuples.

Comment: Note that in a pure languages such as Haskell, "changing the id of Alex" is as meaningful as "changing `42`". You can not change values. You can still compute with them by applying functions on them to create new values, e.g., `42+2 = 44`. Or even `modifyId alex 33 = ("Alex", 33)` for some suitably defined `modifyId` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, values in Haskell are immutable, you can not change them once they're assigned.  You can create a new tuple with a new id, but certainly not with the syntax you've proposed.  You might want something like this:

```
assignID :: Student -> Integer -> Student
assignID (name, oldID) newID = (name, newID)
```

Then you can use it as

```
type Student = (String, Integer)

alex :: Student
alex = ("Alex", 42)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let newAlex = assignID alex 10
    putStr "Old alex: "
    print alex
    putStr "New alex: "
    print newAlex
```